# xml serialize a generic class with it's generic types

Tags: c#, .net, xml, generics, xml-serialization

I need to serialize to xml a list containing objects of type `Pair<T,U>`. Along with those values, I would also need to serialize the type of it's generics(the type of`T` and `U`).

First, I've created a class PairList to hold the list of the pairs and then I've created the actual class which represents a pair of two values, key and value.

```
 [XmlRoot("pairList")]
        public class PairList<T,U>{
            [XmlElement("element")]
            public List<Pair<T,U>> list;
            public PairList()
            {
                list = new List<Pair<T, U>>();
            }

        }
        public class Pair<T, U>
        {
            [XmlAttribute("key")]
            public T key;
            [XmlAttribute("value")]
            public U value;
            [XmlAttribute("T-Type")]
            public Type ttype;
            [XmlAttribute("U-Type")]
            public Type utype;

            public Pair()
            {
            }
            public Pair(T t, U u)
            {
                key = t;
                value = u;
                ttype = typeof(T);
                utype = typeof(U);
            }
        }
```

Then, I tried serializing it:

```
 PairList<string,int> myList = new PairList<string,int>();
            myList.list.Add(new Pair<string, int>("c", 2));
            myList.list.Add(new Pair<string, int>("c", 2));
            myList.list.Add(new Pair<string, int>("c", 2));
            myList.list.Add(new Pair<string, int>("c", 2));
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PairList<string, int>));
                TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("list.xml");
                serializer.Serialize(tw, myList);
                tw.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception xe)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(xe.Message);
            }
```

Unfortunately I am getting an exception: `There was an error reflecting type: PairList[System.String,System.Int32]`. Any ideas on how I could avoid this exception and serialize the class are welcome.

If I choose not to serialize the `ttype` and `utype` fields(by making them protected or private) the serialization works. I can't figure out why it doesn't want to serialize the `Type` fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your class  as

```
public class Pair<T, U>
{
    [XmlAttribute("key")]
    public T key;
    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public U value;
    [XmlAttribute("T-Type")]
    public string ttype;
    [XmlAttribute("U-Type")]
    public string utype;

    public Pair()
    {
    }
    public Pair(T t, U u)
    {
        key = t;
        value = u;
        ttype = typeof(T).ToString();
        utype = typeof(U).ToString();
    }
}
```

and it should work. You can not serialize/deserialize `Type` with `Xmlserializer`.(For example, suppose `T` is a complex object defined in an external assembly and this assembly does not exist on the computer where you want to deserialize)