# How to serialize to XML generic classes?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, xml-serialization

I have these interfaces:

```
public interface IParameter
{
    string Name { get; }
    object UntypedValue { get; set; }
}
public interface IValidationPolicy<T>
{
    bool Validate(T toValidate);
    T Default();
}
```

A parameter base class

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class ParameterBase : IParameter
{
    public abstract string Name { get; protected set; }
    public abstract object UntypedValue { get; set; }
}
```

A parameter concrete class (I have more but them are quite similar):

```
public class Parameter<T, V> : ParameterBase where V : IValidationPolicy<T>
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public override string Name { get; protected set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    protected V validation_policy_;
    [XmlElement("AnyValidation", Type = typeof(AnyValidation<>))]
    [XmlElement("MultiOptionsValidation", Type = typeof(MultiOptionsValidation<>))]
    [XmlElement("RangeValidation", Type = typeof(RangeValidation<>))]
    [XmlElement("TextValidation", Type = typeof(TextValidation))]
    public V Validation
    {
        get
        {
            return validation_policy_;
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    protected T value_;
    [XmlElement("Value")]
    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return value_;
        }
        set
        {
            if (validation_policy_.Validate(value))
            {
                value_ = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public object UntypedValue
    {
        get
        {
            return Value;
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And an XMLParameter class:

```
public class XMLParameter : INotifyPropertyChanged
{        
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int PasswordLevel { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public ParameterBase Parameter { get; set; }
}
```

How can I serialize and deserialize a list of XMLParameters?

In particular I have problem on serializing the IParameter objects.

Since the interface is not serializable as first attempt I created a base abstract class `ParameterBase` and derive the `Parameter` from it.
But when I try to serialize it in a test method:

```
var validation = new RangeValidation<int>() { MinValue = 1, MaxValue = 6 };
var parameter = new Parameter<int, RangeValidation<int>>();
parameter.Initialize("NumberOfTrays", validation);
parameter.Value = 6;

XElement par = validation.ToXElement<Parameter<int, RangeValidation<int>>>();
```

I got an exception: Error at reflection of type `'ConfigurableLibray.Parameter'2[System.Int32,ConfigurableLibray.RangeValidation'1[System.Int32]]'`

The inner exception says that `ConfigurableLibray.Parameter'2[T,V]` is not supported

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011633/xml-serialize-a-generic-class-with-its-generic-types

Comment: Hi CathalMF. If I understood right the problem for him was the two properties of type Type. I do not have any properties of type Type in my class. Am I right?

Comment: Yes but the method is the same. You need to add the attributes to your class. Your problem is that the serializer has no idea what your object is. You need to specify what it is and how to represent it in XML by specifying the root and attributes etc.

Comment: I added the attributes, what am I missing?? Can you reference me a guide where to learn better how to set them?

Comment: Ok found what I was missing, thank you for leading me to the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved implementing manually the serialization and deserialization of the classes using reflection.